# How bitbake searches for recipe in build process?

Tags: yocto, recipe

I am trying to find out that how bitbake search for recipe in build process ?
For example,
I have a recipe something like below:

```
DESCRIPTION = "PetaLinux GSTREAMER supported packages"

inherit packagegroup

GSTREAMER_PACKAGES = " \
    gstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-python \
    gstreamer1.0-meta-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
    gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server \
    gst-shark \
    gstd \
    gst-perf \
    gst-interpipes \
    "
GSTREAMER_PACKAGES_append_zynqmp = " gstreamer1.0-omx"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "${GSTREAMER_PACKAGES}"
```

When I searched *gstreamer1.0* related recipe in yocto layers, I found two recipe, one of them is *gstreamer1.0_1.16.1.bb* in **meta** layer, and the other is *gstreamer1.0_%.bbappend* in **meta-petalinux** layer.

Both of these layers was added to the *BBLAYERS* in *bblayers.conf* file and the priorities that spesified with *BBFILE_PRIORITY_** in related layer's layer.conf file is same.

So,
Which recipe will be used in build process in that case ?
What is the recipe lookup rules in yocto ?

I changed somethings to understand the behaviour:
For example,

1. I entered the invalid github URL that spesified in **gstreamer1.0_%.bbappend** recipe. When I tried to build the linux system, I encountered with an error. Thats fine.
2. Then I corrected the github URL in this recipe and entered invalid source code address that spesified in **gstreamer1.0_1.16.1.bb** recipe. When I tried to build linux system, process finished successfully.
3. Then I increased the priority of **meta** layer. I supposed to encounter with an error in this case but again build process finished successfully.

Could you please help me to understand this behaviour ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different files: a `.bb` and a `.bbappend`.

A `.bb` is the base recipe of one (or multiple) packages. It generally describe how to fetch, configure, compile, install files in a package for your target.

A `.bbappend` file is an 'append' file. It allows a meta (here meta-petalinux) to modify an existing recipe in another meta without copying it. A `.bbappend` can modify any steps of the bb file: source fetch, configure, compile, install...

You can for example create your own bbappend of Gstreamer, to enable pango (disbaled by default on my Yocto). The bbappend filename is `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_%.bbappend` and only contains `PACKAGECONFIG_append = "pango"`

The Yocto Manual can give you more information on bbappend files [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-bbappend-files).